# Is java8 method reference need declaring type explicitly

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror, method-reference

I have write a method

```
    // CheckedFunction<T, R> is a functionality interface has a method apply which throws a checked exception
    public static <T, R> R nullToDefault(T object, R defaultObject, CheckedFunction<T, R> function) {
        return isNull(object) ? defaultObject : nullToDefault(sneakyInvoke(object, function), defaultObject);
    }
```

which use in many modules, all of the usage doing correct in runtime only one place (in a jar file)

```
    public static String getSessionAddr(IoSession session) {
        if (session != null) {
            return LINE_WRAPPER + "sessionId=" + session.getId() +
                   ";local=" + nullToDefault(session.getLocalAddress(), "null", Object::toString) +
                   ";remote=" + nullToDefault(session.getRemoteAddress(), "null", Object::toString) +
                   ";service=" + nullToDefault(session.getServiceAddress(), "null", Object::toString) + LINE_WRAPPER;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

In this method, `Object::toString` is being identified as `Function<T,R>`, so I got a `NoSuchMethodError`.

If I identify `Object::toString` as a `CheckedFunction<Object, String>` explicit, the problem will disappear.

This situation makes me confused.

Did I write something wrong somewhere???

Can someone tell me what's going on here. Thanks!

---

Here is all of the relate method I wrote:

```
    public static <T, R> R nullToDefault(T object, R defaultObject, CheckedFunction<T, R> function) {
        return isNull(object) ? defaultObject : nullToDefault(sneakyInvoke(object, function), defaultObject);
    }

    public static <T, R> R nullToDefault(T object, CheckedFunction<T, R> function) {
        return nullWithConvert(object, function);
    }

    public static <T, R> R nullWithConvert(T object, CheckedFunction<T, R> function) {
        return isNull(object) ? null : sneakyInvoke(object, function);
    }

    public static <R> R nullToDefault(R object, CheckedSupplier<R> function) {
        return isNull(object) ? sneakyInvoke(function) : object;
    }

    public static <T, R> R nullToDefaultSupplier(T object, Supplier<R> supplier, Function<T, R> function) {
        return isNull(object) ? nullToDefault(supplier, Supplier::get) : function.apply(object);
    }
```

Comment: Is there another overload of `nullToDefault`?  (That seems actively likely: perhaps you're compiling against a library with that overload, and running against a library without it.  That would explain the `NoSuchMethodError` rather than the compile error.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I do write several overload method, but each of them has different arguments type or length, I'll post all of them later

Comment: I feel like you are reinventing the `Optional.map` and `Optional.orElse` methods...

Comment: @Sweeper, Yes, I do intend to rewrite it, because I need to implement checked exception handling, like `CheckedFunction`, `CheckedSupplier`, `CheckedConsumer`...